# Should I use CSS grid layout for a detailed list(table)?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using CSS grid layout for my website layout, and now I wonder if I should somehow implement CSS grid for a list of detailed elements. Like Mac finder files list for example:
[image]

The thing is: I generate a div for each row(using VueJS, but it's not the issue), and it wraps the items that supposed to be the grid items - which means they are not direct children of the grid container. For example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-1">1</div>
    <div class="item-2">2</div>
    <div class="item-3">3</div>
    <div class="item-4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-1">10</div>
    <div class="item-2">20</div>
    <div class="item-3">30</div>
    <div class="item-4">40</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-1">100</div>
    <div class="item-2">200</div>
    <div class="item-3">300</div>
    <div class="item-4">400</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 3fr;
  width: 100%;
  .item-1 { background: red; }
  .item-2 { background: yellow; }
  .item-3 { background: green; }
  .item-4 { background: blue; }
}
```

Any chance to achieve such a table like that, or it must be 100% direct children of the grid container? example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item-1">10</div>
  <div class="item-2">20</div>
  <div class="item-3">30</div>
  <div class="item-4">40</div>
  <div class="item-1">100</div>
  <div class="item-2">200</div>
  <div class="item-3">300</div>
  <div class="item-4">400</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it largely depends on if your columns are fixed-width or dynamic. For dynamic tabular content, I would recommend just using a `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) works great for this. `.row` won't wrap because it defaults to `flex-wrap: nowrap`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.item-1 {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.item-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item-3 {
  background: green;
}

.item-4 {
  background: blue;
}

.item-2,
.item-3,
.item-4 {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-1">1</div>
    <div class="item-2">2</div>
    <div class="item-3">3</div>
    <div class="item-4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-1">10</div>
    <div class="item-2">20</div>
    <div class="item-3">30</div>
    <div class="item-4">40</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-1">100</div>
    <div class="item-2">200</div>
    <div class="item-3">300</div>
    <div class="item-4">400</div>
  </div>
</div>
```